# checkbox change on recycler view after every data load

Tags: android, api, mobile, android-recyclerview

i want to use a `checkbox` on items in `recyclerview` i load data from the server 4 by 4 (after seeing the last item he add another 4 new item)but the problem when add new items the checked item change to another item idon't know why i want to save every item checked on `SharedPreferences` to use them on commande activity

some pictures :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn5dv.png)
after going dow i found another item checked and the firs one uchecked :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syuPp.png)
**card.xml**

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>     android:id="@+id/card_view"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="119dp"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:elevation="3dp"
>     card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
>     card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
>     card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:text="ID Article : "
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>
>             android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_reference1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_above="@+id/txt_des"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
>             android:text="Reference : "
>             android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
>             android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_des1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_prix"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_prix"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:text="Prix : "
>             android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
>             android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_des"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>             android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_prix1"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_prix1"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_prix"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_prix1"
>             android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_des1"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_des1"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_idArticle"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_reference"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_reference1"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_reference1"
>             android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_reference1"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_reference1"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txt_prix1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_reference1"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
>             android:text="Designation : "
>             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>             android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
>
>         <CheckBox
>             android:id="@+id/checkBox"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:text="panier"
>             android:textSize="10sp" />
>
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>
> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> ```

**recherche_art.java**

```
package com.example.bacha.pfe.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bacha.pfe.R;
import com.example.bacha.pfe.adapter.ArticleAdapter;
import com.example.bacha.pfe.classes.Article;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class recherche_art extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private ArticleAdapter adapter ;
    private List<Article> data_list ;
    private String recherche_article;
    private ImageButton btnrechArt ;
    private EditText arech;
    int d;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recherche_art);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

   btnrechArt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnrechArt);

        recherche_art.this.onRestart();

        btnrechArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                d=0;
                Log.d("PFE", String.valueOf(d));
                arech= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextRechArt);
                data_list  = new ArrayList<>();
                recherche_article=arech.getText().toString();

                load_article_from_server(d);
                gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(recherche_art.this,1);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

                adapter = new ArticleAdapter(recherche_art.this,data_list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
        });


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if(gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == data_list.size()-1){
                    d=data_list.size();

                    load_article_from_server(d);
                    Log.d("PFE", String.valueOf(d));
                }

            }

        });

    }


    private void load_article_from_server(final int id) {

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer,Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... Params) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://10.0.2.2/slim/article/"+recherche_article+"/"+id).build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Article data = new Article(/*dd,*/object.getString("id_Article"),object.getString("Reference"),object.getString("Designation"),object.getString("PVTTC"));
                        data_list.add(data);

                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.print("End of content");
                }


                return  null ;
            }



            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        task.execute(id);

    }
}
```

**activity_recherche_art.xml**

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:text="Recherche Article :"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/textView"
>     android:textSize="24sp"
>     android:textStyle="normal|bold"
>     android:textAlignment="center"
>     android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
>
>
> <ImageButton
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:src="@drawable/recherche"
>     android:id="@+id/btnrechArt"
>     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eTextRechArt"
>     />
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:inputType="textPersonName"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:id="@+id/eTextRechArt"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
>     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnrechArt"
>     android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnrechArt" />
>
> <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>     android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     article_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
>     article_view:cardElevation="5dp"
>     article_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
>     android:scrollbars="vertical"
>     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/btnrechArt"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
> ```

**Article.java**

```
package com.example.bacha.pfe.classes;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by BACHA on 07/03/2017.
 */
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String id_Article,Reference,Designation,PVTTC;


    public Article(/*int id,*/ String id_Article, String reference, String designation, String PVTTC) {
       // this.id = id;
        this.id_Article = id_Article;
        Reference = reference;
        Designation = designation;
        this.PVTTC = PVTTC;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId_Article() {
        return id_Article;
    }

    public void setId_Article(String id_Article) {
        this.id_Article = id_Article;
    }

    public String getReference() {
        return Reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        Reference = reference;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return Designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        Designation = designation;
    }

    public String getPVTTC() {
        return PVTTC;
    }

    public void setPVTTC(String PVTTC) {
        this.PVTTC = PVTTC;
    }
}
```

ArticleAdapter.java

```
package com.example.bacha.pfe.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.bacha.pfe.R;
import com.example.bacha.pfe.activity.ArticleDetail;
import com.example.bacha.pfe.classes.Article;

import java.util.List;

import static com.example.bacha.pfe.R.layout.card;

/**
 * Created by BACHA on 08/03/2017.
 */

public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static Context context ;
    private List<Article> my_data ;


    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, List<Article> my_data) {

        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;




    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(card,parent,false);

        return new ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.id_Article.setText(my_data.get(position).getId_Article());
        holder.Reference.setText(my_data.get(position).getReference());
        holder.Designation.setText(my_data.get(position).getDesignation());
        holder.PVTTC.setText(my_data.get(position).getPVTTC());
        holder.root.setTag(my_data.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView id_Article,Reference,Designation,PVTTC;
         View root;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            root = itemView;




root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Article art = (Article)v.getTag();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ArticleDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("REFERENCE", art.getReference());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

            id_Article=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_idArticle);
            Reference=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_reference);
            Designation=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_des);
            PVTTC=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_prix);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please show **Article** class code.

Comment: visit this.it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items

Comment: check this you will get an idea for it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075352/updating-views-within-a-single-row-of-a-listview-when-clicked/43182640#43182640